# Neural Network on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, neural-network, aforge

I am trying neural network application on Windows Phone 8. And I am writing below code:

```
ActivationNetwork network = null; //global variable

network = new ActivationNetwork(
            new BipolarSigmoidFunction(2),    //aktivation func.
            9,                                //input count
            20,                               //hidden layer count
            1                                 //output count
            );
```

This code working on desktop project.(C#) But not working Windows Phone 8.

This is Aforge Framework's function. I installed via nuget.

When I clicked run I am getting error. My error code:

*An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in PanoramaApp2.DLL but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Type 'AForge.Neuro.BipolarSigmoidFunction' from assembly 'AForge.Neuro, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2094f4ea39731d4f' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.*

What is my problem?

How can i succeed?

Thanks in advance. (sorry my language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the official version which is on Nuget does not support Windows Phone. Check this link: http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3061

Comment: Problem has solved. I added manually .dll files, .cs files and another files https://github.com/cureos/aforge. You shouldn't use nuget for using aforge on Windows Phone.