# Neural Network on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, neural-network, aforge

I am trying to write using aforge(neural network) framework on Windows Phone 8 application and   I installed PCL version [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge).

I wrote below code:

Pivotpage.xaml.cs

```
_inputDataGelen = new double[4] { 0.067, 0.033, 0.057, 0.021 };

double compute = network.Compute(_inputDataGelen)[0]; // (1)
//MessageBox.Show("Output is "+ Math.Round(compute));
```

I am trying same code on desktop application and I am getting *compute* as 0.00112.. or 0.01283.., 0.02123.., 0.03231.., 0.04159... So if I round to one digit 0,1,2,3,4...

But when I tried on Windows Phone 8 project, I am getting *compute* like a 0.9999995345.

What is my problem.

Thanks in advance. (sorry my language.)

Comment: Of what type is the `network` variable, and how have you initialized it?

Comment: I used the initialization from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23717779/650012) except that I changed *input count* from 9 to 4. Calling `Compute`, I get values close to 1 regardless of when I try this on Windows Phone (with the *Cureos* binaries) or if I try it in a console application with the NuGet assemblies. Can you please show the desktop application code that yields the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop code:

```
 ActivationNetwork network = null; //global variable
 bool dongu = false;
 ...
 ...

 network = new ActivationNetwork(
            new BipolarSigmoidFunction(2), //activation func.
            4,                             //input count
            20,                            //hidden layer count
            1);                            //output count     

        //Learning Network
        BackPropagationLearning backprob = new BackPropagationLearning(network);
        backprob.LearningRate = 0.1;
        backprob.Momentum = 0.0;

        int iteration = 1;
        double hata = 0.0;
        //loop
        while(!dongu)
        {
            hata = backprob.RunEpoch(_inputData, _outputData);

            iteration++;

            if (iteration > 10000 || hata < 0.0001)
                break;

        }

        double a1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        double a2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        double a3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        double a4 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);

        //Actually devide 100. Not 1000.
        double[] girdi = { a1/1000, a2/1000, a3/1000, a4/1000 }; //normalize


        textBox1.Text = network.Compute(girdi)[0].ToString() + " compute"; //output ile aynı değer geliyor

        double find = network.Output[0]*100; //denormalize

        //textBox2.Text = (network.Output[0]).ToString() + " output"; //compute ile aynı değer geliyor

        //tam sayıya yuvarlama
        find = Math.Round(find,1);


        if (find >= 0.0 && find <= 1.7) //bu aralık optimize edilebilir
        { 
            //MessageBox.Show("Iris-setosa");
            textBox7.Text = "1";
        }

        else if (find > 1.7 && find <= 2.6) 
        { 
            //MessageBox.Show("Iris-versicolor");
            textBox7.Text = "2";
        } 

        else if (find > 2.6 && find <= 3.7) 
        { 
            //MessageBox.Show("Iris-virginica"); 
            textBox7.Text = "3";
        }
```

Train set is [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/m.herbster/GI07/week4/iris.data.txt)

@Anders Gustafsson, this code working on desktop. If I enter 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2 double numbers I am giving output is 1.

Comment: Osman, I'll look into this in more detail when I have the time. Meanwhile, I think you should consider moving the text from the "answer" to your original question and delete the answer post. Or, to facilitate further discussion, post this whole question as an issue on Github, [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/issues?state=open).

Comment: Ok @AndersGustafsson I wrote this problem on github. I am trying to solve and waiting helps. Thx.

Comment: Problem is solved.I defined some functions incorrect position :/ it is my mistake. So sorry @AnderGustafsson. So thanks everything.

Comment: Glad that things worked out for you in the end, Osman. If you run into other issues with the PCL/WP8 AForge, do not hesitate to report them on the [Issues site on Github](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/issues?state=open).